# An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in

Tags: vb.net

I'm getting a error while calling this function "An unhandled exception of type 'System.OverflowException' occurred in"

```
Public Structure GlowStruct
    Public r As Single
    Public g As Single
    Public b As Single
    Public a As Single
    Public rwo As Boolean
    Public rwuo As Boolean
End Structure

Private Sub DrawGlow(ByVal pGlowIn As Int32, ByVal col As GlowStruct)
    Dim pGlowObj = Mem.ReadInt(bClient + Offset.oGlowObject, 4)
    Mem.WriteSingle(pGlowObj + ((pGlowIn * &H38) + &H4), 4, col.r)
    Mem.WriteSingle(pGlowObj + ((pGlowIn * &H38) + &H8), 4, col.g)
    Mem.WriteSingle(pGlowObj + ((pGlowIn * &H38) + &HC), 4, col.b)
    Mem.WriteSingle(pGlowObj + ((pGlowIn * &H38) + &H10), 4, col.a)
    Mem.WriteBool(pGlowObj + ((pGlowIn * &H38) + &H24), 1, col.rwo)
    Mem.WriteBool(pGlowObj + ((pGlowIn * &H38) + &H25), 1, col.rwuo)
End Sub
```

Comment: What value do you send as `pGlowObj`? - By the way how's the multithreading going? :)

Answer (score 1):

When you multiply pGlowObj it is being treated as an integer still.  Presumably pGlowObj * &H38 exceeds the maximum value for an integer.

Since you want a Single at the end anyway of the calculation anyway, just force pGlowObj to be a single to start with, and then it won't overflow:

```
Dim pGlowObj as Single = Mem.ReadInt(bClient + Offset.oGlowObject, 4)
```